# Converting set to .csv using for loop

Tags: python, csv, python-3.8

I am trying to convert a Python set of URLs to a .csv file using a for loop.  I'm using Python 3.8. The set contains 116 unique URL's. However, my output .csv file has over 6000 comma-separated values in the file.

```
c = open('task_links.csv', 'w')
cw = csv.writer(c, lineterminator='')
mylist = []
for x in myset:
    mylist.append(x)
    if not mylist:
        continue
    else:
        cw.writerow(mylist)
c.close()
```

Comment: Do you want one URL per row? Because your list is growing every iteration of the for loop

Comment: Yes, I want 1 url per row.  I am also fine with 1 url per column.  It is a school assignment, so as long as I get 1 url per cell in the .csv file as all that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row and multiple columns:

```py
with open('task_links.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(list(myset))
```

If you want one column and multiple rows

```py
with open('task_links.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for url in myset:
        writer.writerow([url])
```

Comment: I got an error message with both of these, but when I converted the set to a list first  it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending each URL in your set to `mylist` and then writing the whole list into your CSV file. This should work:

```
c = open('task_links.csv', 'w')
cw = csv.writer(c, lineterminator='')
mylist = []
for x in myset:
    mylist.append(x)
    cw.writerow(x)
c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to the pandas packages

```
import pandas as pd

set_of_links = set(["https://www.link{}.com".format(i) for i in range(116)])
df = pd.DataFrame(set_of_links, columns=['links'])
df.to_csv('task_links.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I am new to python.  Haven't worked with pandas yet.